# Ant symlink with same names

Tags: maven, ant, symlink, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm trying to create a symlink with Ant's `symlink`.
Actually it's Maven 3.6 + Antrun plugin 1.8.

```
<symlink link="${basedir}/scripts"   failonerror="true"
      resource="content/Resources/module/scripts/" />
```

At first run, it creates the `${basedir}/scripts` as expected.

However, on a second run, it creates `${basedir}/scripts/scripts`. This causes later steps to fail.

I don't want to use `overwrite="true"` because there might be a real directory under `${basedir}/scripts`.

Is this a bug/known feature, or am I doing something wrong?